# Why do I get error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firstnamef is null"?

Tags: svelte, prisma, sveltekit

Why do I get this error randomly in sveltekit? It still gets the value result.firstname from the endpoint using prisma every time.

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firstnamef is null"

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import { session } from '$app/stores';

  let firstnamef;
  let result;

  async function setValues() {
    const response = await fetch('./api/actions?id=' + $session.userID, {
      method: 'get',
    });
    result = await response.json();
    firstnamef.value = result.firstname;
  }

  onMount(async () => {
    setValues();
  });
</script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" bind:this={firstnamef} />
```

Comment: By the way, you usually should not need to access DOM elements directly. Instead of binding `this` here, the `value` could be bound directly, which also would not cause any problems on component destruction.

Comment: Of course. How stupid of me. Explains the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the component is destroyed (e.g. navigation away might cause that). After destruction the DOM reference will be `null`.

[REPL demonstration](https://svelte.dev/repl/2b95425c5aec4389bd484cf40a3fd1e5?version=3.48.0)

It this is the case you can either check the DOM reference for `null` or track the component state using the `onDestroy` hook.